Why is ‘ă·yā·rîm translated as both "donkey" and "town" in Judges 10:4?
In this interlinear for Judges 10:4, I see "‘ă·yā·rîm" (Strong's 5895) translated as both "donkey" and "town" in the same verse. Why was this done?

There are two problems here; first, "city" should be tagged as H5892, and "donkey/ass" should be tagged as H5895 (see this more reputable and better-maintained interlinear published by Cambridge.) second, they are the same word in the sense that they share the same spelling; this is why it is important to use a resource that offers a side-by-side view of all dictionary entries for a given word rather than just one. See the difference between this entry and this entry. The first contains information for both "city" and "donkey/ass" side by side, whereas the second only contains information for "donkey."

This is the correct answer, but it's worth noting that the words are identical only in the singular form. The plurals generally differ, this text uses an incorrect or non-standard plural, which is why the OP's source is confused.

The words for donkey and city are very similar and written identically in the singular (note that the diacritics are a much later addition). While the plural forms would generally differ, the text here uses an incorrect/non-standard plural form, whether in error or as an intentional word play. It's clear both from the context of this verse and others that reference Havoth-Jair (e.g. Numbers 32:41) that the author does indeed mean "cities" and not "donkeys".
